# Same space distance between lines with different responsive font sizes

Tags: html, css, responsive

How could I achieve texts sticking to each other no matter the size of each one. What happens now is that there are different gaps between `test <> test_2` and `test_2 <> test_3`. Especially when resizing `div`.

```
<div>
    
    <div style="font-size:2vw">test</div>
    <div style="font-size:10vw">test2</div>
    <div style="font-size:3vw">test3</div>
    
  </div>
```

[image]

https://jsbin.com/koqobexuna/edit?html,output

Comment: the differing heights are partly due to the optical illusion caused by the space allowed for ascenders and descenders - does it look better if you use LgWy as your test word. Each line also has a line-height associated with it - nominally about 1.2em, which obviously changes as the font-size changes - you could try fixing the line-height to a specific height (but be aware that this may cause overlapping)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the displayed text - e.g. lowercase letters with **large descenders** or capital letters – you can't avoid different spaces between the lines.
See also: ["Typography – The Anatomy of Letters"](https://www.loveofgraphics.com/typography/typography-letters/)

You can only mitigate this effect by adjusting your design/layout concept:

- switch to uppercase letters via `text-transform: uppercase;`
- crop your lines to cap height using a pseudo-element with negative margins
- add absolute margins between the line divs (using px or rem units)

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  gap: 2em;
}

.uppercase {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.line:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 1px;
  margin-bottom: -0.18em;
}

.line {
  line-height:1em;
  margin-bottom: 1vw;
  position: relative;
  height: 0.66em;
  outline: 1px dotted red;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">

  <div class="heights">
    <div class="line" style="font-size:2vw">ghx </div>
    <div class="line" style="font-size:10vw">gxx </div>
    <div class="line" style="font-size:3.5vw">hhh </div>
    <div class="line" style="font-size:1vw">hhh </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="heights uppercase">
    <div class="line" style="font-size:2vw">ghx </div>
    <div class="line" style="font-size:10vw">gxx </div>
    <div class="line" style="font-size:3.5vw">hhh </div>
    <div class="line" style="font-size:1vw">hhh </div>
  </div>

  <div class="heights uppercase">
    <div class="line" style="font-size:2vw">hhh </div>
    <div class="line" style="font-size:10vw">hhh </div>
    <div class="line" style="font-size:3.5vw">hhh </div>
    <div class="line" style="font-size:1vw">hhh </div>
  </div>

</div>
```